# Maven project compile error: cannot find symbol (which is java.lang.String)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

It's a very simple web scraping program that I built in intellij idea with the maven build system. It worked fine before today but when I tried to build it today it gave me object not found errors for base java objects like String and List. When I tried to reload the maven project I got another error below. Idea also highlights the basic java object in red and gives no advice. The only thing I did was slightly modify the java source code. So, I tested with the stock hello world code. It did compile and run, but Intellij still highlights String and System in red and the maven reload produces the same error. Help is greatly appreciated as I need to get some data for a research project.

Error with web scraping source code compilation error

```
Error:(24, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class List
  location: class Main
```

Maven reload error

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:${maven.compiler.version}
```

This is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunittest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: go to intellij menu File ->  project structure -> project setting - > select your JDK

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the problem. JDK is 11.

Comment: @T0m4t0s4uc3 Did you try adding this to ur pom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

After resolving the maven errors, since you are facing IDE related problems, I would suggest you to do this:

1. Go to File > Project Structure

[image: IntelliJ1]

2. Add the JDK in Project SDK (If it is not there, under Platform Settings > SDKs, you need to add the JDK)

[image: IntelliJ2]

3. Also ensure that maven home is set correctly in Preferences > build tools > maven:
   [image: IntelliJ3]
4. Then do a maven rebuild from the side panel:
   [image: IntelliJ4]

---

You have forgot to define the property `${maven.compiler.version}` in your POM.

Define a `properties` section in your POM like this:

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what I need to do. I'll be honest I haven't learned maven as well as I need to. Just to point it out the same POM worked in the past. I may have updated Intellij before last time I ran it.

Comment: Please add this section after `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` in your POM. Change the java version if required

Comment: tried it and maven error goes away, thanks. However, objects being highlighted in red and source not compiling is still a problem.

Comment: Ok one error gone. Dont remove this `properties` I will update what you need to resolve Intellij issue

Comment: @T0m4t0s4uc3 can u please try doing all these?

Comment: Yep, I followed your post. No changes to the settings nor project structure. I'm not exactly sure what you meant by a maven rebuild. No change, same problem. Thanks a ton for the help tho, sorry I had to step away for a minute

Comment: By maven rebuild, I meant, in my step 4 diagram, that small 'refresh' button you are seeing. Clicking on that

Comment: If that too doesnt work, try closing IntelliJ, deleting the .idea folder from your project directory and then re-importing again

Comment: Okay, something worked!!! I didn't delete the .idea folder I removed the dependencies then closed Intellij. Opened the program up again, then pasted the dependencies. I copied my original source code back to the Main file and got my data!!!  Very odd bug. Thanks a ton for your help!!!